# Why haven't I been paid yet for In-App purchases made on my app?

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I have an app with one In-App Purchase item. When looking at the *Payments and Financial Reports* the *Estimated Amount Owed* is > 300 DKK (I'm from Denmark).

[image]

However, there's been no payment yet. **What am I missing?**

I checked in *Agreements, Tax, and Banking* and I have a *Paid Application* contract in place with Bank Info.

Comment: I believe Apple tallies everything up at the end of each month, and then sends it to you about 30 days after that. So I wouldn't expect money from a July 6th in-app purchase until the end of August at the earliest.

Comment: When reading https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/books/faq/Payments%20and%20Financial%20Reports_Getting%20Paid# I should get payed when I have $10 - and that happened long time ago (more that half a year ago).